# Angular 2+ add dynamically html text on div with "onChange" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I've developed an app that dynamically changes the HTML text in a div element as soon as the value in the select element changes.

In HTML:

```
<div id="update"></div>
```

In Typescript:

```
$('#update').html(`<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">`
```

It works. When I select a file, the function is not called.

Comment: Its best practice try avoid using jquery inside angular applications.

Comment: jQuery can't compile angular code. You are trying to render, at runtime, an angular script that needs to be compiled. To accomplish such, either avoid using jQuery at all, either use angular's dynamic component creation https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d . You likely are approaching it in the wrong way in any case, since it seems to be an easy task that can be done with angular without jQuery at all.

Comment: Why are you adding it dynamically? Not implying you shouldn't, just want to understand to see if I could help.

Comment: It is necessary to dynamically integrate the html text, because it does not work with the ngModule specially *ngIf.  If I set a flag in a div box (for example, * ngIf = "x === 1), it will only be checked at compile time, and if the value of the select box is changed, the html text will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
var html = $compile('<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)"')($scope);
 $('#update').html(html);
```

Comment: This procedure does not work anymore from Angular 2. `$compile` was abolished with the introduction of NgModule.

Answer (score 0):

Remove jquery code and set a flag for a div. When user click on button the flag should be change. according to flag status you can set your text.

Comment: If I set a flag in a div box (for example, * ngIf = "x === 1), it will only be checked at compile time, and if the value of the select box is changed, the html text will not change.